# I can't install pyaudio on M1 mac

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pyaudio, macos-big-sur, apple-m1

I tried installing PyAudio in the default terminal and visual studio code on M1 mac, running python 3.8, macOS 11.2.1 BigSur and this is the error that i got:

```
 MacBook-Pro-Jakubik:~ kuba$ pip3 install pyaudio
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.11.tar.gz (37 kB)
Using legacy setup.py install for pyaudio, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: pyaudio
    Running setup.py install for pyaudio ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8h/c3rxt5m1367cq61wy64pl67c0000gp/T/pip-install-yzoe7_ph/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8h/c3rxt5m1367cq61wy64pl67c0000gp/T/pip-install-yzoe7_ph/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8h/c3rxt5m1367cq61wy64pl67c0000gp/T/pip-record-jzsqhn9q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pyaudio
         cwd: /private/var/folders/8h/c3rxt5m1367cq61wy64pl67c0000gp/T/pip-install-yzoe7_ph/pyaudio/
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    copying src/pyaudio.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    running build_ext
    building '_portaudio' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -DMACOSX=1 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c src/_portaudiomodule.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/src/_portaudiomodule.o
    src/_portaudiomodule.c:29:10: fatal error: 'portaudio.h' file not found
    #include "portaudio.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/8h/c3rxt5m1367cq61wy64pl67c0000gp/T/pip-install-yzoe7_ph/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';__file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/8h/c3rxt5m1367cq61wy64pl67c0000gp/T/pip-install-yzoe7_ph/pyaudio/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/8h/c3rxt5m1367cq61wy64pl67c0000gp/T/pip-record-jzsqhn9q/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/pyaudio Check the logs for full command output.
```

Answer (score 0):

pyaudio needs the [portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com) library. It is probably easiest to install it with [homebrew](http://brew.sh) (assuming it has been ported to the M1 architecture).

Comment: just throws out another error `Error: no implicit conversion of Array into Integer`

Comment: That is a *completely* different issue, which should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message, GCC can't find your PortAudio installation. Since you probably installed PortAudio using Homebrew, you can try relinking it like so:

```
brew unlink portaudio
brew link portaudio
```

And the retry installing PyAudio as you tried before.